# docker-compose V1 works but docker compose V2 is failing with the same docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following command in my `docker-compose.yml` -

```
command: |
      /bin/bash -c "export ORACLE_ALLOW_REMOTE=true && \
         su oracle -c '/u01/app/oracle-product/12.2.0/SE/bin/lsnrctl start' && \
         su oracle -c 'echo startup\; | /u01/app/oracle-product/12.2.0/SE/bin/sqlplus -S / as sysdba' && \
         date && sleep 60s && date && \
         /bin/bash -c 'if [[ $$(find /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/DmgrProfile/config/cells/PCCell1/key.p12 -mtime +360 -print) ]]; then /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/DmgrProfile/bin/startManager.sh; echo \"Sleeping for 3mins to let certs renew\"; sleep 180; else echo \"No need to renew certs. Normal startup.\"; fi' && \
         /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/bin/BPMConfig.sh -start /Advanced-PC-SingleCluster-Oracle.properties && \
         sleep 10 && \
         find /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/ -name SystemOut.log | xargs tail -F
      "
```

It works just fine if I start using the `docker-compose` that is V1 version of compose. But if I start it using `docker compose` that is V2 version then it fails with the following error -

```
bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
bash: -c: line 0: `echo startup; | /u01/app/oracle-product/12.2.0/SE/bin/sqlplus -S / as sysdba'
```

If I try double quotes on this line -

```
su oracle -c "echo startup\; | /u01/app/oracle-product/12.2.0/SE/bin/sqlplus -S / as sysdba" && \
```

Then it just exits `exited with code 1` without executing the command(s) at all.

Comment: I'm not especially familiar with the set of technologies you're invoking here, but it looks like you could simplify this by breaking it into two separate containers (one running the Oracle component and one running Websphere) and then inside the container using an entrypoint wrapper script to do the certificate refresh.  Can you avoid this problem by not having a Compose `command:` override at all?

Comment: Thank you for your response. The issue is that I am doing an override because the image is already built and I don't have control over it. So, the override is more of a workaround but I hear you and I believe that would be a more appropriate solution rather than troubleshooting this.